# Keeping characters out of integer input in C

Tags: c

I have a C program that prompts for an input of a 13-digit integer (long long). But the user may accidentally input some characters. How can it avoid crashing or looping by ignoring all the characters in the input?

Comment: it's not clear what you want. If the user types 1234abcde5678, do you want to treat it as 12345678, or 1234 followed by 5678? or do you want to treat it as an error?

Comment: thereis cin.ignore() to ignore some characters but doesnt check if it is numeric or non-numeric

Comment: "*I have a C program ...*" You could start by showing us what you already have.

Answer (score 4):

1. input a string
2. check all the characters in the string are digits

   - if the input is invalid: complain and exit, or re-prompt and `goto 1`, or whatever makes sense for your app
3. convert your (validated) string to an integer value

Answer (score 1):

In c I would do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char str[1000];
    int i;
    int newLength = 0;
    long long l;

    scanf( "%s", str );

    for ( i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        if ( isdigit( str[i] ) )
            str[newLength++] = str[i];
    }
    str[newLength] = '\0';
    sscanf( str, "%d", &l );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/):

> On success, the function returns the number of items successfully
>   read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer,
>   even zero, if a matching failure happens.